# Script Error in jquery draagable in IE Quirks Mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I am working on Jquery Draggable. Everything is working fine is ,but except the page is flickering a lot in IE Quricks mode. Does any one faced this  issue before or is it is a problem with jQuery UI itself. What could be the root cause for this

Please find the fiddle URL

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/68k5h/5/

Comment: Simple fix: make your HTML valid so that IE doesn't ever use quirks mode.

Comment: i already added the meta tag to the html as <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>  but still i am facing the same issue

Comment: That's not enough. You need to run the code through the W3C validator and fix all the issues it lists

Comment: W3C Validator... ok i will google it to see how it helps me :)

Comment: The main thing you need to do to get out of quirks mode is to have a valid doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply: neither jQuery nor jQueryUI are designed to work in Quirks Mode.

So the solution is to should make sure that the page is not in quirks mode.

You can do this by doing the following:

1. Add a valid doctype to the top of your page. This can be any valid doctype, but if you're not sure which one to use, try this one:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```

   Make sure that is the very first line of code, before the `<html>` tag.
2. That will solve the problem most of the time, but if you are still in quirks mode, check with [the W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) for any other HTML errors you may have, and fix them.